# RStudio fatal error when using 'edgar' package to parse keywords from 10-K's

Tags: r, edgar

I'm trying to use the 'edgar' package to parse 10-k's for specific keywords (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgar/edgar.pdf).

My code works fine when testing with just a few companies, but I need to do this for ~8000 companies over 9 years. First problem arose when I ran out of disk space, but splitting the companies into smaller chunks seemed to be the easy fix. Now that I have the relevant files downloaded, I try to run the code to get the count of the keywords, it often crashes at around 80% with the fatal error message, and no further information.

Is there any way I could perform this in a more reliable way?

Splitting the company list into smaller chunks solved the disk space error, but parsing the downloaded files seems to crash RStudio around 80% usually (fluctuates, sometimes works sometimes not)

Below is the code I'm using

```
testicik120170.5 <- searchFilings(cik.no = cik0.5, form.type = c("10-K"),
                              filing.year = c(2017), word.list, useragent)
write.csv(testicik120170.5, "cik0.5-2017.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have read in other contexts that the SEC has tried to make it difficult to do "scraping activities". The solution in some cases has been to use an "agent" that appears to be a browser. Perhaps something with a headless browser?